# Can all of Bluemix's services be used in a mobile application?

Tags: mobile, service, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to create a mobile application and use some Bluemix services.

I see a section for "Mobile" in my bluemix account, which includes : 
     
Mobile Application Content Manager

     Mobile Client Access

     Mobile Foundation

     Mobile Quality Assurance

     Push Notifications

     Kinetise

     Testdroid Cloud

     Twilio

Are these the only services supported for mobile apps? Or can I connect to other bluemix services as well, say for example a Watson Speech to Text service?

Thanks in advance,

Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can connect the other services!

The Mobile services are specific to Mobile applications. This is why they are under the Mobile header in Bluemix, but many of the other services include their own Mobile SDKs.

For example, here's a link to the Watson Developer Cloud Mobile SDKs where you can add Watson services to your app:

- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk
- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk

---

Here's a brief overview of the **Bluemix Mobile** services that I posted as an answer for another question.

Here are the current services that we have and a bit of information about them that follow the MBaaS pattern and here's some links for how to get started):

**Mobile Client Access**

This service enables you to secure your Mobile Application. You can add Facebook, Google, or custom authentication to your application.

**Push Notifications**

You can add the Push Notifications service to send push notifications to your app on Android and iOS.

**Mobile Analytics (Beta)**

The Mobile Analytics service enables you to gather crash and usage knowlege about customers using your mobile app.

**Cloudant NoSQL DB**

The Cloudant service is the IBM NoSQL database to store your data.

**Object Storage**

The Object Storage service is an unstructured cloud data store where you can store things like images or files.

---

**Mobile Foundation**

The catalog also includes the Mobile Foundation service which you can use to create a test environment before deploying or purchasing the on-premise software. This service is another way for enabling a developer to create a mobile channel.

Comment: **Mobile Foundation** is missing from the list above

Comment: You can also directly connect to many of the services without the use of a helper API kit.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty, Do you mean we can use the services without using the SDK? How can I do this?

Comment: The Services are just REST API calls. The Helper API's put a wrapper around it so you don't have figure out how it's structured. If you go to the related Watson service, and look at the CURL examples in API reference. It will show you the endpoint, call (post/get/etc) and payload.

Comment: @ChaitanyaT See this recent answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39127499/1167890

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty - Just a side note that if you go the route of calling REST APIs directly - the mobile app developer has to hand code all the features the above mobile specific services offer (app security, lifecycle, Push, security etc).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, this helps a lot